# How to create a shared variable between fragments in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

currently, my Kotlin based application consists of a single activity, 3 fragments and a navigation (with navigation drawer) between them.

How do I add a variable, which will be initialized in the start of the application, will be visible in all fragments, and can be updated in one of them?
a simple int or string for that matter so it should be with little overhead as possible, yet i'd like to follow correct coding conventions. Please elaborate on the correct function to perform the initial variable value, how to bind each fragment textview to it, and the correct way to set the new value.

Thanks!

Comment: one way would be to create a viewmodel scoped to your main activity

Comment: @Sekiro do you mean in contrary to scoped to one of the fragments?

Comment: yes, if the view models are scoped to fragments, then for each and every fragment, a different instance of view models will be assigned but if it's scoped to the containing activity, then the same instance of ViewModel is assigned to all the fragments requesting the viewmodel. check out @Abdulaziz Rasulbek answer

Comment: Thanks, @Abdulaziz answer makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Create ViewModel and fragments use viewmodel like this

```
val viewModel: YourViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

in that case your viewmodel's scope is the same as activity scope.
For more information please refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

Comment: Thanks, i got this much, but I am missing important information such as how to bind the xml element ( such as text edit) to this model